# Vuetify JS Click event issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

There's an error with the v-app component, I think. I used the dev tools from Chrome to check which component was triggering the click event again and it seems to be the app component.

As you can see these are the three steps when I stoped dragging on the grid.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]

### What is expected?

User should be able to drag and select multiple items and at the end of the dragging a dialog should appear.

[JSBin Here](http://jsbin.com/xoziyus/edit?html,js)

```
<div id="selector">
    <v-row>
        ...
```

Without the v-app element, everything works just fine.

Reproduction Link [JSBin Here](http://jsbin.com/soyitij/edit?html,js)

```
<v-app id="example-4" v-cloak>
    <div id="selector">
        <v-row>
            ...
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with event propagation?